# how to convert var to dictionary and access var using foreach loop

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, generics, var, generic-collections

i have a dictionary defined as follows:

```
Dictionary<string, int> Controls = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

using the following code i am putting keys which have similar value into var

```
var result = (from p in Controls
                         group p by p.Value into g
                         where g.Count() > 1
                         select g);
```

But neither i am able to convert 'result' into dictionary again or nor i am able to access item inside 'result'

i tried this code but

```
foreach (System.Linq.Lookup<int, KeyValuePair<string, int>> Item in result)
{

}
```

Plz help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var dict = result.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(y => y.Key).ToList())
```

and access it like

```
foreach(var item in dict)
```

BTW, there's no type `var`. It's just [instruction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) for the compiler to determine type for variable, but it's strongly typed. In your case, I think, it would be `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>`. Actually you can access `result` like this too:

```
foreach(var item in result)
{
    // item is type  Lookup<int, KeyValuePair<string, int>>.Grouping
    //  you can go through item like
    foreach(var i in item)
    {

    }

    // or convert it ToList()
    var l = item.ToList()
    // l is type List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply it worked for me. There is one more thing if u can help. How to access 'tempdic' using 'foreach' loop                               Dictionary<int,List<string>> tempdic = result.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(y => y.Key).ToList());